# Does a while loop rerun the random number generator?

Tags: python-3.x

Ok, I have looked and looked and I cannot find the answer to my question. This is the basic dice rolling game from week 2 of my Python class and while my script is working just fine but I had trouble with the random 6 side dice roll repeating itself (or stuck in what appears to be a loop) when I put it before the while loop. After inserting the random dice roll inside the While loop it appears that I have solved that problem and that the While loop is helping with randomization. Am I correct in my assumption?

```
while True:
DoWeRunIt = input('Do you roll the dice?')
#setup random numbers for dice roll
die1 = random.randint(1,6)
die2 = random.randint(1,6)
die12 = die1 + die2
try:
    RunIt = int(DoWeRunIt)
    if RunIt == 1:
        if die1 == 1 and die2 == 1:
            print('A ' + str(die1) + ' and a ' + str(die2) + ' - Snake Eyes')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`die1 = random.randint(1,6)` doesn't create a 'die-operator'. It just generates a number between 1 and 6. So if you put it before the while loop, it will stay at that value. When you put it in the while loop, a new value is generated every iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much, that explained it.